# Creating new feature class in ArcPy gives error 000210?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, error-000210

I am trying to create a new attribute table and I keep getting the same error.

```
import os
import arcpy
import math
folderpath = 'C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\GEOG M173'

arcpy.env.workspace = folderpath
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

input_shp = folderpath + '\lower48_county_2012_election.shp'
out_shp = folderpath + '\new_48_county.shp'

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management (input_shp, out_shp)
```

my error is:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\GEOG M173new_48_county.shp
Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).
```

Comment: + r'\shapefile' should fix it. Error message answers your question

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the issue I had with that line of code!